# VB.net auto number increase even after close form

Tags: vb.net

I have trouble to increase the number of my codex. Example: I have this kind of codex **JJ01** where 01 will keep increasing every time new data type in. I understand that you can `dim i as integer` and use `i += 1` but that will be reset once I closed the form.

I try the other way around by using ID from database and take it +1 but that will be a long way as you need to open database take ID and keep on some textbox and plus it with 1 change back to string.

Therefore, is there any other way to do that?

Comment: you can store in a file by create it

Comment: similar thing I still need to code open file then do math +1 then save it back

Comment: try add to app.config

Answer (score 0):

Create the ID the Settings of your Project, so you can access it via `My.Settings.ID`.

More Info on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bc6ws923.aspx)

Comment: where I create that ID? new ID textbox ?

Comment: Project Settings > Settings

Comment: I have found the way but the value is still 0 even after `My.Setting.Save()`

Comment: @VithcheaTry : So update your question with your new code. Without anything to examine there's nothing any of us can do to help you fix that.